# Can I add two tuples to form a new tuple using the coerce() function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to add two tuples two create a new sort of nested tuple using the  coerce function of python.

I'm  using python version 3.7 which is showing that the function isn't defined.

It is supposed to be a built-in function in python

Comment: "create a new sort of nested tuple" is a bit vague. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#coerce), it only worked to coerce numeric types to be compatible, and it won't contribute to helping create a nested tuple or do anything aside from element-level conversions.

More importantly, [it no longer exists](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#coerce-and-coerce).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `coerce`:

```
In [16]: t1 = (1,2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [17]: t2 = (3,4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [18]: t1 + t2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[18]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```